# Questions about transition from a function to a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

For example:
We know that
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$

and we can do some substitutions to this like substitute the x for 2x, then we get

$$\frac{1}{1-2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^n$$

I can understand this step sice we can rewrite the term like $2^n(x-0)^n$, it fits the general form of power series, which is $c_n(x-a)^n$.

However, if we substitude it by $x^2$, the form is $x^{2n}$, this do not fit the general form at all but still it work, what really confusing is someone told me that we can substitute by a $x^n$ where n is a possive intgeral number, but like $\sqrt{x}, 1/x$, we can not substitute, why? Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: Note that this equality only holds for $|x|<1$

Comment: If you write $x = f(t)$ in such a manner that $x$ is still of absolute value $< 1$, then you can write $$\frac{1}{1 - f(t)} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty f(t)^n$$ without problem. What that other person was getting at is most likely that for nonlinear $f$ that series, while viable, is not a *power series* representation of $\frac{1}{1-f}$.

Comment: @BrunoB You mean that the only requirement is the interval of convergence, right? So I can substitute $x$ by whatever I like, my friend only want to say some subsitutions are not power series, right?

Comment: Yes, you can substitute by whatever you want, it's just that in most cases it won't correspond to a power series indeed.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks a lot, get your point

Answer (score 2):

First, let us make clear that we are talking about real funcions of a real variable on the left side and series wih real coefficients on the right side. Second, note that there are two kinds of series (i) formal series where you don't concern yourself with  convergence at all but just regad a series as a function $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ and (ii) series wih an actual number for $x$, where you care about whether or not $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{n=i}^n(g(x))^i\text { exists.}$$ Let's assume that you are concerned eith the latter kind of series. So you can start with he formula $$\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y^n \text{ for }-1<y<1$$ and a function $g: \text{ subset of }\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and replace $y$ by any $x$ such that $g(x)$ is defined and $-1<g(x)<1$. Depending on the function $g$ and the value of $x$, what you get on the right side may or may not be a power series.